# no video media player

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I have a problem with playing video in mediaplayer. I have a sound but no video. I tried everything and can't find solve. Or maybe you know how to play sdp file in videoview? Here's the code:

```
public class TestStream1 extends Activity implements Callback{
MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer;
String SrcPath = "rtsp://184.72.239.149/vod/mp4:BigBuckBunny_175k.mov";
private SurfaceView mPreview;
private SurfaceHolder holder;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    mPreview = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.surface);
       holder = mPreview.getHolder();
       holder.addCallback(TestStream1.this);
       holder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);

       holder.setFixedSize(400,300); 
       mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(); 
       try{
           mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(SrcPath);
           mMediaPlayer.setDisplay(holder);
           mMediaPlayer.prepare();
           mMediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
           mMediaPlayer.start(); 

       }catch(Exception e){
           Toast .makeText( TestStream1.this, "Fail", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
       }

}
@Override
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width,
        int height) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
@Override
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
}
```

EDIT: layout file

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  >
<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello" />
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <SurfaceView
            android:id="@+id/surface"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some videos *cannot be* played in mediaplayer, if it doesn't have the codec for its a/v or it is too complex or badly interleaved (Look at Logcat for signs about some). Could be one or more reasons. To make sure the mediaplayer can play the type of video you are asking it to play, save a video file of the same a/v codec and extension to your sd card and then try to play it using the default media player. 
Meanwile, try using a **videoView** to check the video can be played.Your code seems all right.

Try this code :

package a.b;

```
public class TestStream1 extends Activity implements Callback{
    MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer;
    String SrcPath = "rtsp://184.72.239.149/vod/mp4:BigBuckBunny_175k.mov";
    private SurfaceView mPreview;
    private SurfaceHolder holder;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        mPreview = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.surface);
        holder = mPreview.getHolder();
        holder.addCallback(TestStream1.this);
        holder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);

        holder.setFixedSize(400,300); 
        mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(); 

    }
    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width,
            int height) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try{
            mMediaPlayer.setDisplay(holder);
            mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(SrcPath);
            mMediaPlayer.prepare();
            mMediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
            mMediaPlayer.start(); 

        }catch(Exception e){
            Toast .makeText( TestStream1.this, "Fail", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }
    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
mMediaPlayer.release();
    }
}
```

SurfaceHolders are created ansynchronously, so we have to wait until the surface has been created and then assign the returned surface holder object .
And I am using the following layout:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  >
<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello" />
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <SurfaceView
            android:id="@+id/surface"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

The above solution should work.

Comment: I tried to do same thing in videoView and it works good there was sound and video. The only one problem is with media player. Do mediaplayer and videoview uses the same codecs?

Comment: yup, they use the same mediaplayer. VideoView is just a wrapper of the surfaceHolder and is very convenient. It means the code needs to be checked. You can go for videoView if u can. Post your layout xml if you dont want to and we will try to correct the code. :)

Comment: i mean if you dont want to use a videoview and continue with a surface view

Comment: Yes i need surface view. But you said that they have same codecs, it means that they can play same file format? I posted xml file.

Comment: I have edited the code added.please take the latest one. Hope it works for you.

Comment: Thanks a lot man it works! Big up for u it was a real problem for me. I see that you are good i this and because of that i have another question to you. Does media player can play sdp file format or i need something more to do?

Comment: ok i found solve for second question, i was't able to play sdp file becaues it had to high quality and it throws error. I use very very low quelity and it works.

Answer (score 1):

Note sure, but try setting the datasource like:

```
mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(this, SrcPath);
```